# determine whether the function accepts parameters

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I wrote the wrong code for jest test.

```
test('init data', (done) => {
  expect(services.getList).toHaveBeenCalled();
  // accept done as param, but not called
});
```

I got the expected error:

> Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout
>   specified by jest.setTimeout.

But if I remove `done` param, is **passed**:

```
test('init data', () => {
  expect(services.getList).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

How does jest **know** that I accepted the `done` parameter? It's magical!

Comment: Be sure to read the tag descriptions when tagging, [tag:jest] isn't [tag:jestjs]. :-) I've fixed it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does `jest` know that I accepted the done parameter?

With those two code examples, there are two ways it could know:

1. By looking at the `length` property of your callback, which will be `1` in the first case but `0` in the second case. The `length` of a function is its *arity* (the number of formal parameters it declares¹).
2. By using `Function#toString` and parsing the code it provides. That's not something you'd want to do in production code in the general case, but it's absolutely fine for testing tools.

Example:

```js
function test(label, callback) {
  console.log(`${label}: length: ${callback.length}`);
  console.log(`${label}: toString(): ${callback.toString()}`);
}
test('init data', (done) => {
  // ...
});

test('init data', () => {
  // ...
});
```

---

¹ In JavaScript, it's the number of formal parameters it declares not counting the rest parameter, if any, or any parameters from the first parameter with a default value onward.